# boost asio with little endian

Tags: c++, boost-asio, endianness

I am integrating a library that requires little endian for length.  It's formatted with little endian and then a custom serialized object.  How do I convert 4 byte char into a int?  The little endian tells me the size of the serialized object to read.

so if I receive "\x00\x00\x00H\x00"  I would like to be able to get the decimal value out.

my library looks like

```
char buffer_size[size_desc]
m_socket->receive(boost::asio::buffer(buffer, size_desc));
int  converted_int = some_function(buffer); <-- not sure what to do here
char buffer_obj[converted_int];
m_socket->receive(boost::asio::buffer(buffer, size_desc));
```

Comment: That example value looks like a big endian 72

Comment: I will reply the vendor,  Thank you @rustyx

Comment: @MichaelWS it should be noted that big endian is also known as "network byte order". Historically packet headers and many protocols operate with big endian. Socket libraries have function like `ntohs` to "convert" those network values to "host byte order" values. (so bswap on little endian and do nothing if your platform is already big endian)

Comment: So it's a normal tcp/ip protocol, I  am used to sending some delimiter  on a protocol such as this.

It's 4 bytes, 1 char,  serialized object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a simple solution you could do couple of tricks,
Reverse with a cast:

```cpp
// #include <stdafx.h>
#include <cassert>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    char buff[4] = {3,2,1,0};

    std::cout <<  (*reinterpret_cast<int*>(&buff[0])) << "\n";

    std::reverse(buff, buff+4);

    std::cout <<  (*reinterpret_cast<int*>(&buff[0]));

    return 0;

};
```

---

Boost also comes with an endianness library:
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/endian/doc/html/endian.html#buffers

You can use the built in types, like:

- big_int32_t
- little_int16_t